# Group by variable in data.table and carry on other variables

Tags: r, data.table

I am working on some summaries for financial datasets and I would like to sort the summary in regard to a certain criterion, but without loosing the remaining summary values in a row. Here is a simple example:

```
set.seed(1)
tseq <- seq(Sys.time(), length.out = 36, by = "mins")
dt <- data.table(TM_STMP = tseq, COMP = rep(c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4)), 3), SEC = rep(letters[1:12],3), VOL = rpois(36, 3e+6))
dt2 <- dt[, list(SUM = sum(VOL), MEAN = mean(VOL)), by = list(COMP, SEC)]
dt2
   COMP SEC     SUM    MEAN
1:    A   a 9000329 3000110
2:    A   b 9001274 3000425
3:    A   c 9003505 3001168
4:    A   d 9002138 3000713
```

Now I would like to get the SEC per COMP with highest VOL:

```
dt3 <- dt2[, list(SUM = max(SUM)), by = list(COMP)]
dt3
   COMP     SUM
1:    A 9003505
2:    B 9002888
3:    C 9005042
```

This gives me what I want, but I would like to keep the other values in the specific rows (SEC and MEAN) such that it looks like this (made by hand):

```
   COMP     SUM SEC    MEAN
1:    A 9003505   c 3001168
2:    B 9002888   f 3000963  
3:    C 9005042   k 3001681
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: how are you determining which values to keep in each row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for the SEC and the MEAN corresponding to max of SUM:

```
 dt3 <- dt2[, list(SUM = max(SUM),SEC=SEC[which.max(SUM)],MEAN=MEAN[which.max(SUM)]), by = list(COMP)]
> dt3
   COMP     SUM SEC    MEAN
1:    A 9003110   a 3001037
2:    B 9000814   e 2999612
3:    C 9002707   i 2999741
```

---

**Edit:** This'll be faster:

```
dt2[dt2[, .I[which.max(SUM)], by = list(COMP)]$V1]
```

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I looked for. Now, where I see it, it seems obvious to use `which`, but I was too much into finding an innate data.table solution. Thanks for the solution @Metrics!

Comment: No problem. You may want to accept the answer if this is what you are looking for. See here for how to accept an answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Hi Simon, if this solution answers the question, make sure to indicate by clicking the checkmark. Also, no need to write "+1", you can simply upvote the answer ;)

Comment: @Arun Like! This as short as it gets I think. Especially when I have a lot of columns I can use this very efficiently! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this would be to `setkey` of the data.table to: `COMP, SUM` and then use `mult="last"` as follows:

```
setkey(dt2, COMP, SUM)
dt2[J(unique(COMP)), mult="last"]
#    COMP SEC     SUM    MEAN
# 1:    A   c 9002500 3000833
# 2:    B   g 9003312 3001104
# 3:    C   i 9000058 3000019
```

---

**Edit:** To answer to Simon's benchmarking about speed differences between this and @metrics':

```
set.seed(45)
N <- 1e6
tseq <- seq(Sys.time(), length.out = N, by = "mins")

ff <- function(x) paste(sample(letters, x, TRUE), collapse="")
val1 <- unique(unlist(replicate(1e5, ff(8), simplify=FALSE)))
val2 <- unique(unlist(replicate(1e5, ff(12), simplify=FALSE)))

dt <- data.table(TM_STMP = tseq, COMP = rep(val1, each=100), SEC = rep(val2, each=100), VOL = rpois(1e6, 3e+6))
dt2 <- dt[, list(SUM = sum(VOL), MEAN = mean(VOL)), by = list(COMP, SEC)]

require(microbenchmark)

metrics <- function(x=copy(dt2)) {
    x[, list(SUM = max(SUM),SEC=SEC[which.max(SUM)],MEAN=MEAN[which.max(SUM)]), by = list(COMP)]
}

arun <- function(x=copy(dt2)) {
    setkey(x, COMP, SUM)
    x[J(unique(COMP)), mult="last"]
}

microbenchmark(ans1 <- metrics(dt2), ans2 <- arun(dt2), times=20)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                  expr      min       lq   median       uq       max neval
#  ans1 <- metrics(dt2) 749.0001 804.0651 838.0750 882.3869 1053.3389    20
#     ans2 <- arun(dt2) 301.7696 321.6619 342.4779 359.9343  392.5902    20

setkey(ans1, COMP, SEC)
setkey(ans2, COMP, SEC)
setcolorder(ans1, names(ans2))

identical(ans1, ans2) # [1] TRUE
```

Comment: +1 @Arun Indeed, for large datasets the 'innate' approach plays out and one should keep this in mind when using ordering functions, as here this approach can be used with an intense speed-up.

Comment: SimonZ., Yes, great!. And you may want to check out the edit I've made to @metrics' post (just occurred to me). That should be much more efficient as it just calls 1 function as opposed to a max and 2 which.max(es). That is more general than the current solution, I believe, you'd agree (as you don't have to write down each and every column).

Answer (score 2):

from your sample output, it's not exactly clear what you would like to keep / drop, but you can simply list your additional columns in the `j` argument of `DT[i, j, ]`

```
> dt2[, list(SUM = max(SUM), SEC, MEAN), by = list(COMP)]
    COMP     SUM SEC    MEAN
 1:    A 9007273   a 3000131
 2:    A 9007273   b 3000938
 3:    A 9007273   c 2999502
 4:    A 9007273   d 3002424
 5:    B 9004829   e 3001610
 6:    B 9004829   f 2999991
 7:    B 9004829   g 2998471
 8:    B 9004829   h 2999571
 9:    C 9002479   i 3000826
10:    C 9002479   j 2999826
11:    C 9002479   k 3000728
12:    C 9002479   l 2999634
```

Comment: +1 This is something I also found during my experiments with the data.table. What I want to have is the maximum SUM with corresponding SEC and MEAN at this maximum value grouped by COMP. Next time I try to  check more often my data output. Apology!

Answer (score 1):

I was very interested in the performance of the two different approaches from @Metrics that I denote in the following as `which.func` and from @Arun that I denote as `innate.func`. So, I made some benchmarking with my example given in the question above. Here are the results:

```
which.func <- function() {dt3 <- dt2[, list(SUM = max(SUM), SEC=SEC[which.max(SUM)], MENA=MEAN[which.max(SUM)]), by = list(COMP)]}
innate.func <- function() {dt3 <- dt2[J(unique(COMP)), mult = "last"]}
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(which.func, innate.func, replications = 10e+6)
        test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
2     innate     10000000  24.689    1.000    24.259    0.425
1 which.func     10000000  32.664    1.323    32.216    0.446
```

Of course this is maybe a little unfair towards the which.func becuase the `innate.func`involves a call to `setkey`, which is especially for large samples a time consumer. If I include the `setkey`call into the function I get the following:

```
innate.func <- function() {setkey(dt2, COMP, SUM); dt3 <- dt2[J(unique(COMP)), mult = "last"]; setkey(dt2, NULL)}
         test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self 
2 innate.func     10000000  25.271    1.000    24.834    0.430 
1  which.func     10000000  26.476    1.048    26.062    0.397
```

It seems, that the two approaches have a very similar performance. The approach of @Arun has perhaps a more elegant style in regard to the data.table and needs less code. Its disadvantage may come with different aggregation functions than the `max`or `min`, where the approach of @Metrics plays out its character of being able to be applied in a more general setting.

I learned from both approaches and put them into my toolbox.

Comment: @Simon, I agree with the limitation reg. usage for `max/min (even though that's a given). It's specifically for that task. But I don't think that the speed will be the same. I've made an edit to my post with benchmarking on bigger data to show this.

Answer (score 0):

During my further work with the solutions given here I encountered another problem with the summary shown above in my question and I found a solution to it, that I would like to share.

If I want to provide a choice to the user for

1. an aggregation function, denoted by `aggregate` and
2. a criterion (variable of the summary) the `aggregate` method should be applied to, denoted by `crit`,

then I encounter the problem, that I have to check, which of the columns are remaining (see e.g. @Metrics answer that uses the which). A simple example:

We take data.table `dt2` from my question above. A user now, wants to apply the `aggregate = "max"` method on the `crit = "SUM"` variable in the data.table summary of `dt2`. Here is a solution I found out that works fine (any discussion of course appreciated):

```
aggregate = "max"
crit = "SUM"
user call <- expression(do.call(aggregate, list(get(crit))))
dt2[, .SD[which(get(crit) == eval(mycall))], by = COMP]
dt2
   COMP SEC     SUM    MEAN
1:    A   c 9002500 3000833
2:    B   g 9003312 3001104
3:    C   i 9000058 3000019
```